# Text not showing if image on background

Tags: android, background, textview

i am tried set image on background of textview. All ok but .. when i "setText("blyablya")" than text not showing. I am tried to use setBackgroundResource and setBackgroundDrawable... but always on background only image and i can't see text from TextView (((

Please can anyone help me ??

simple code :

```
//tit - TextView tit
tit.setText("blabla");
        tit.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tit.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.popup_title));
```

added after help : if normal drawable than all ok but if background drawable is a 9patch than this might help you.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you set the background and then set the text?

Comment: Maybe Android rejects "blabla" strings? =)

Comment: nope ( i tried set bacgkround in layout and than add to this layout my TextView... but result = 0 :( Can't see text

Comment: Egor, nope :)there are all good :)

Comment: have you tried setting another color for text?

Comment: yeah, white,red,blue,green,yellow  but result will be 1... image on background and not text.. But if i  myText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)//example.. than i see my text..

Comment: is the bg drawable a 9patch? maybe there are problems with paddings?

Comment: yeah 9patch.. sorry forgot about it .  What u mean problem with paddings ?

Comment: upper and left black lines define the stretchable areas, right and bottom lines define the content area. If the content area is small, there might just not be space for the content (the text)

Comment: thank u buddy.. set ur comment as answer.. and i set as solved after 22 hours

Comment: @Peter I used xml which is under drawable folder. Dynamically tried to set the background using both setBackgroundDrawable and setBackgroundResource. The text is hidden. without those the text appearing. what should I have to do to show the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your background drawable is a 9patch, check that the content area (defined by bottom and right black lines) is wide enough to contain the text, because it might be hidden by the padding itself.

(thanks @Peter)